# C# classes and struct

Tags: c#, class, struct, serializable

i have some problem with serialization in C#
Have Code:

```
public struct CoOrds
{
    public double x, y, z;

    public CoOrds(double p1, double p2, double p3)
    {
        x = p1;
        y = p2;
        z = p3;
    }
}
public struct printColor
{
    public int r, g, b;

    public printColor(int p1, int p2, int p3)
    {
        r = p1;
        g = p2;
        b = p3;
    }
}
[Serializable]
public abstract class shape : ISerializable
{
    public int borderStyle=1;        
    /*  ===============================COLOR PARAMETERS================================ */
    public printColor colorRGB = new printColor(0, 0, 0);



    public System.Drawing.Drawing2D.DashStyle styleLine { get; set; }
    public int widht=2;

    /*=================================FILL PARAMETERS=====================================*/
    public printColor fillColorRGB = new printColor(255,255, 255);
    public shape()
    {
    }

    protected shape(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        colorRGB.r = info.GetInt32("colorLine.r");
        colorRGB.g = info.GetInt32("colorLine.g");
        colorRGB.b = info.GetInt32("colorLine.b");
        borderStyle = info.GetInt32("borderStyle");
        fillColorRGB.r = info.GetInt32("fillColorRGB.r");
        fillColorRGB.g = info.GetInt32("fillColorRGB.g");
        fillColorRGB.b = info.GetInt32("fillColorRGB.b");
        widht = info.GetInt32("widht");

    }

    public virtual void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        info.AddValue("colorLine.r",colorRGB.r);
        info.AddValue("colorLine.g", colorRGB.g);
        info.AddValue("colorLine.b", colorRGB.b);
        info.AddValue("borderStyle",borderStyle);
        info.AddValue("fillColorRGB.r", fillColorRGB.r);
        info.AddValue("fillColorRGB.g", fillColorRGB.g);
        info.AddValue("fillColorRGB.b", fillColorRGB.b);
        info.AddValue("widht", widht);
    }
 .....
```

1. how i can serializable struct like

```
[Serializable]
public struct CoOrds
```

under the class and how the put it in shape and GetObjectData, because i have too many classes where i must use this struct

Thx

Comment: @user1137147: don't really understand your problem. What if you save the *content* of the structs inside binary serialization, like you do with, for example, `colorline.R` ?

Comment: Now i wanna know about serializable only

Comment: I can leave this like now,  but i have too many code where i must do this serializable  and if i could do it easier i do it

Comment: Mutable structs are evil. Try to avoid using them unless absolutely necessary.

Comment: Is there some reason why you have to implement `ISerializable`? Are the `struct`s marked as `[Serializable]` or not?

Comment: fields can changed, so i use ISerializable,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly serialize it with `info.AddValue("Pos", pos, typeof(CoOrds)` or you can convert to/from `string`.

```
[Serializable()]
public struct Coords
{
    readonly public double x, y, z;

    public Coords(double x, double y, double z)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.z = z;
    }

    public static Coords FromString(string value)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value)) return new Coords();
        double x = 0,y= 0,z = 0;
        string[] parts = value.Split(',');
        if (parts.Length > 0) double.TryParse(parts[0], out x);
        if (parts.Length > 1) double.TryParse(parts[1], out y);
        if (parts.Length > 2) double.TryParse(parts[2], out z);
        return new Coords(x, y, z);
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        //Ensure round-trip formatting
        return string.Format("{0:R},{1:R},{2:R}", x, y, z);
    }

}
```

and then serialize it with

```
[Serializable()]
public class Vertex : ISerializable
{
    public Coords pos1, pos2;
    ...
    public void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        info.AddValue("Pos1", pos1.ToString());
        info.AddValue("Pos2", pos2, typeof(Coords));
    }
    public Vertex(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        this.pos1 = Coords.FromString(info.GetValue("Pos1", typeof(string)) as string);
        this.pos2 = (Coords)info.GetValue("Pos2", typeof(Coords));
    }
}
```

With work equally well with the test code I did.

Comment: Ooooo! It is what i search, Thx